# time complexity without for loop

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity

code:

```
x=[10,20,30,40,50]       
y=20    
if(y in x):   
  print(x.index(y))   
else:
  print(-1)
```

Please help me with the below 2 Questions

1. in the above code will the time complexity be O(n)?
2. Is it that for time complexity to be O(n) there has to be a for loop?

Comment: "Is it that for time complexity to be O(n) there has to be a for loop?" no.

Comment: But yes, this code is O(N). Both checking `y in x` and `x.index(y)` are linear time operations